# Fail on formatting portable storage on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo, nexus-5

I create one Android Emulator with these configurations:

- Nexus 5X with Play Store.
- API level 26.

I run this emulator and receive one notification that I need to "Set up your Virtual SD card". There are 2 options in here:

- Use as portable storage.
- Use as internal storage.

I try to choose one of 2 options, follow its setup but at the end I receive the toast message below:

> command '37 volume partition disk: 253, 48 public' failed with '400 37 Command failed'

However, my portable storage doesn't format successfully.

Therefore, how can I resolve this problem?